# When I hit play Unity removes Game Objects from scripts

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm making an android game, but the game objects are dropped from the scripts when I hit play. I can't find a way to fix it. I uninstalled and reinstalled Unity, I reset my whole computer, but every time I hit play all game objects are dropped from the script. I even made a new project with a game object that I attached to a script and it still gets removed when I hit play.

[This is before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXFgX.png)

[This is after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZAvh.png)

Comment: is there something in your script thats reassigning values? post the relevant code please

Comment: Post the ball script. The issue is likely what @ryeMoss said

Comment: This issue persists with any script with a game object attached.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot with your hierarchy visible and can you post your ball script?

Answer (score 0):

It's not getting removed. It is because you have a rigidbody2d component and it is reacting to gravity. If you don't want it to be affected by gravity but want to move it yourself then change the body type to kinematic. If you gravity but don't want it to fall through then make sure you have something at the bottom that can collide with it.

Comment: Sorry didn't understand which game object you were talking about. Yeah, I agree with those above. You are probably reassigning it somewhere in the ball script.

Comment: Please consider including sample source code in your to provide more clarification and value to your answer

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found out the issue was that I was using GetComponent<GameObject>() to get the game objects and that was causing the missing component exeption.